# Shellsort - if an array is g-sorted then h-sorted, the array is still g-sorted

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Following is an exercise from coursera's algorithm course from Princeton.

If an array is both 3-sorted and 5-sorted, then is it also 6-, 7-, 8-, 9-, and 10-sorted ?
I know that any sequence if g-sorted then h-sorted, it still is g-sorted. But how does this explain the question? If an array is 3-sorted and 5-sorted, how does it relate to being 6-sorted or 7-sorted etc ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of g-sortedness?

Comment: @Pradhan Suppose we have a sequence [1st 2nd 3rd 4th 5th 6th ...] to be sorted. And we choose to do a 5-sorting(g=5 in this case)
So the 1st element will be compared to 6th element and if the 1st element is greater then they will swap. The swapping sequence will continue till the end of the sequence is reached. So the sorting is done on [1st 6th ath 13th 18th ...] and so on.
This is called 5-sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with regards to 6, 9, and 10 sorting, these are just alternate entries in the base sorting runs (6-sorting is every other entry in 3-sorting, for instance). So you can say that for an h-sorted array, the array is also kh-sorted, where k is a positive integer larger than 0. 8-sorting is a bit trickier to understand, but it suffices to say that the array is 8-sorted because 8 is the sum of 3 and 5. For a similar reason, we can say that the array is not 7-sorted because you can't construct 7 from 5 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The Array is 3-sorted and 5-sorted.

Any multiple **k** of 3 or 5 (for ex  - k=6,9,10,15 etc) will we **k sorted** for sure.

And other than that sum **h** of 3 + 5 or any of their multiples sum (ex. h=8(3+5),11(5+6),13(10+3),16(10+6)) will remain **h sorted**.

Any sequence **k** not in the above category can't be constructed so they are not **k-sort**(ex k=7).

Answer (score 0):

It's 6,8,9,10-sorted, but not 7-sorted.

a[i]<=a[i+g]<=a[i+g+k] => a[i]<=a[i+g+k], thus g-sorted and k-sorted give (g+k)-sorted (g and k could surely be equal).

Thus 3-sorted and 5-sorted give us 6,8,9,10-sorted. (6=3+3,8=3+5,9=3+3+3,10=5+5)
However we don't have 7-sorted, for exemple:

[4,1,0,5,2,7,6,3] is 3-sorted([4,5,6],[1,2,3],[0,7]) and 5-sorted([4,7],[1,6],[0,3]), but not 7-sorted([4,3]).